# Program in C that returns the number of similar characters between two strings without counting a letter multiple times

Tags: c, for-loop, c-strings, similarity

I a currently trying to make a program in C to return the number of similar characters between two strings, but without counting a letter multiple times.

Checking if two strings are exactly the same too.

For example with "week" and "weak", it should return 3 because the letters 'w', 'e', and 'k' are in both words.

The size of the two strings are 4 only.

I made the "contains" function to check if we didn't already compared a character, for example with "test" and "tast" got 2 "t", so it was returning more than expected.

For now my code, seems to work but not correctly and I can't understand why...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define STRLEN 4

bool contains(char tab[], char c){
    for(int i=0; i<STRLEN; i++){
        if(tab[i] == c){
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int likeness(char* password, char* wordchosen) {

    if(strlen(password)!=STRLEN && strlen(wordchosen)!=STRLEN) {
        return -1;
    }

    if(!strcmp(password, wordchosen)) {
        return 4;
    }

    int like = 0;
    char found[STRLEN];

    for(int i=0; i<STRLEN; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<STRLEN; j++) {
            /*printf("%c : %c\n", password[i], wordchosen[j]);
            printf("\n");*/
            if(password[i] == wordchosen[j] && !(contains(found, wordchosen[j]))) {
                like++;
            }
        }
        found[i] = password[i];
    }

    return like;
}

int main() {
    printf("week and week = %d\n", likeness("week", "week")); // should be 4 (same word even if only 3 (w, e, k))
    printf("test and tast = %d\n", likeness("test", "tast")); // should be 2 (t, s)
    printf("week and weak = %d\n", likeness("week", "weak")); // should be 3 (w, e, k)
    printf("snet and sent = %d\n", likeness("snet", "sent")); // should be 4 (s, n, e, t)
    printf("gree and green = %d\n", likeness("gree", "gren")); // should be 3 (g, r, e)
    printf("mail and main = %d\n", likeness("mail", "main")); // should be 3 (m, a, i)
    printf("same = %d\n", likeness("same", "same")); // should be 4
    // opposite side in the likeness func. return different result...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you use `stdbool.h`, you can also use `true` and `false`.

Answer (score 3):

The array `found` is not initialized

```
char found[STRLEN];
```

So the function `contains` using the uninitialized array invokes undefined behavior.

Another problem is that inside the inner for loop

```
    for(int j=0; j<STRLEN; j++) {
        /*printf("%c : %c\n", password[i], wordchosen[j]);
        printf("\n");*/
        if(password[i] == wordchosen[j] && !(contains(found, wordchosen[j]))) {
            like++;
        }
    }
```

the variable `like` can be incremented several times when the letter `password[i]` is present in the string `wordchosen` more than one time and is not yet written in the array `found`..

Also it seems that instead of this if statement

```
if(strlen(password)!=STRLEN && strlen(wordchosen)!=STRLEN) {
    return -1;
}
```

you should write this one

```
if(strlen(password)!=STRLEN || strlen(wordchosen)!=STRLEN) {
    return -1;
}
```

Pay attention to that instead of your manually written function `contains` you could use standard C string function `strchr` or `memchr`.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STRLEN 4

int likeness( const char *password, const char *wordchosen ) 
{
    if ( strlen( password ) != STRLEN || strlen( wordchosen ) != STRLEN ) 
    {
        return -1;
    }

    if ( strcmp( password, wordchosen ) == 0 ) 
    {
        return STRLEN;
    }

    int like = 0;
    char found[STRLEN + 1] = "";

    for ( ; *password; ++password )
    {
        if ( strchr( wordchosen, *password ) != NULL && 
             strchr( found, *password ) == NULL )
        {
            found[like++] = *password;
        }            
    }

    return like;
}

int main( void )
{
    printf("week and week = %d\n", likeness("week", "week")); // should be 4 (same word even if only 3 (w, e, k))
    printf("test and tast = %d\n", likeness("test", "tast")); // should be 2 (t, s)
    printf("week and weak = %d\n", likeness("week", "weak")); // should be 3 (w, e, k)
    printf("snet and sent = %d\n", likeness("snet", "sent")); // should be 4 (s, n, e, t)
    printf("gree and gren = %d\n", likeness("gree", "gren")); // should be 3 (g, r, e)
    printf("mail and main = %d\n", likeness("mail", "main")); // should be 3 (m, a, i)
    printf("same = %d\n", likeness("same", "same")); // should be 4
}
```

The program output is

```
week and week = 4
test and tast = 2
week and weak = 3
snet and sent = 4
gree and gren = 3
mail and main = 3
same = 4
```

As you can see the function definition does not depend on the value of `STRLEN`.

The function can be defined also without using the auxiliary array.

Here you are.

```
int likeness( const char *password, const char *wordchosen ) 
{
    if ( strlen( password ) != STRLEN || strlen( wordchosen ) != STRLEN ) 
    {
        return -1;
    }

    if ( strcmp( password, wordchosen ) == 0 ) 
    {
        return STRLEN;
    }

    int like = 0;

    for ( const char *p = password; *p; ++p )
    {
        if ( memchr( password, *p, p - password ) == NULL && 
             strchr( wordchosen, *p ) != NULL )
        {
            ++like;
        }            
    }

    return like;
}
```